# How to bind ngmodel to use assign property in ionic alertcontroller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using  Ionic `alertcontroller` to recieve OTP. It is recognising as null in backend because the property is not set correctly in input section of the `alertcontroller`. I tried to use `ngModel` in there, how ever it displays error: this type input is not available.

Comment: Please add your code here. It is impossible to answer without looking at code

Comment: You cannot able to use ngModel in the alert controller. Instead use modal controller for the using ngModel.